# Running two tasks simultaneously in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have two tasks that should be run together.
The first task to save the data to the database. And the second task of recording video.

Currently I use a Thread for each task, and run it simultaneously.

```
...
Thread insertDb = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Insert to Database
                setDataMediaVisit(thumbStr);
                insertVisitRecord();
            }
        });

        Thread capture = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (getGraph().getState() == DSCapture.PREVIEW) {
                    getGraph().setCaptureFile("data/"+ CaptureController.getNoMr() +"/videos/"+videoStr, DSFilterInfo.filterInfoForProfile(new File("profiles/demo_profile800x570_WM8_VBR_100.prx")), DSFilterInfo.doNotRender(), true);
                    getGraph().record();
                }

                setData(CaptureController.getNoMr());
            }
        });

        insertDb.start();
        capture.start();
...
```

Is the above code thread safe?
I want to use EDT, but i know EDT for Java Swing Component. CMIIW

Thank you.

Comment: for better help (to avoids any guessing) post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: Impossible to say. It depends on the nature of the shared state and on the way it is accessed: getGraph(), getState(), setCaptureFile(), record(), etc.

Comment: When you say you're doing them simultaneously, are you just running both tasks at the same time or are you recording and immediately saving that footage to the database?

Comment: @Daniel : Yes, if i am not use the thread, the capture process too long. Save thumbnail to filesystem and insert it to the database. I want to make it not freeze, when save it thumb and db.

Comment: This is very difficult to answer as we don't know/see where shared state could be. Running thread in parallel is always about shared state. Think about reading **Java Concurrency in Practice** which is a fine book about this.

Comment: Your code is fine.  The major concern with thread safety is in maintaining order amoung your fields when multiple threads read and write to them.  You're not showing any fields, and indeed you may not have much trouble that way if your threads don't even use the same classes.

Comment: Though everything is not visible from code, looks like you have a shared resource, make sure you attain a lock when you modify resource.

Answer (score 1):

THread safe is just an issue, when do you want use object that are running in specific thread with another thread. It's not clear here that you are using the share object in this 2 thread or not! But, if you wanna use some share object or you want to read and write from file or specific butter, you can use lock object like this:

```
final Object lock = new Object();

// In thread 1
// TODO: do some process in thread on

synchronized(lock) {
    // TODO: Put the result in somewhere that thread2 want to read it
}


// In thread 2
synchronized(lock) {
    // TODO: get the result from the place that you put in thread 1
}

// TODO: do some process on thread 2 on the data
```

You should always remember that you need to put smallest possible synchronized, because if the other thread reach to synchronized part, it will wait until thread 1 finish synchronized block and it can kill the performance of your code